# how to implement this in GQL(Google Query Language)

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, gql

In MySQL it's like:

select * from table1 where column1 in ('a','b','c');

how to do that in GQL?

Comment: +1 just for introducing me to a new term :-D

Answer (score 5):

[It seems everything is in here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html)

Comment: Go to the main app engine site (http://code.google.com/appengine/).  click on "docs"  then click on "storing data" (under the python heading).  then click "gql reference".

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the following

```
  result = db.GqlQuery("Select __key__ from model where column in ('a','b','c')")
```

or

```
   result = db.GqlQuery("Select * from model where column in ('a','b','c')")
```

The call with _ _ key _ _ is a lot more efficient than the * call on the appengine. It uses less datastore calls as well as less CPU to do it.

Comment: How to make column support full-text search,could you provide a demo?

Comment: as far as I know you can't. Full-Text Searching requires a lot of work from a database. SQL Server for example breaks it up and stores it on the filesystem for faster indexing. TextProperty() and StringProperty() columns can indexed while Blob style columns cant. This means that it will need a lot of work to reduce down the data to do searching on it.

Comment: But gae supports full-text search,so there must be a solution.

Comment: Having searched google it appears it supports it but not very well.

class models(search.SearchableModel):
  text = db.TextProperty()

to search it you would do something like 

model = models.all().search('searchtext') in your business logic
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/4b912691a00eea59/5374a670b210d3e9?lnk=gst&q=searchablemodel#5374a670b210d3e9 

I did see a lot of things saying that it hits your put() call when saving the object. It also looks like it may hit your datastore use a lot!

Comment: Those APIs have hided the true things that are going on,it's the datastore that support full-text search,right?So there must be a syntax for datastore to index and do full-text search,but Google intended not to publish that document yet.

Comment: Yea it looks like that but if you do use it they will hit your counters quite hard. Full-Text Searching is quite a hard thing to do with normal data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Just exactly as you described it works fine - but beware, IN queries are implemented in the Python API, and translate to multiple underlying datastore queries. If there's another way you can fetch the data, I'd highly recommend using that instead.